# Docfx PlantUml Metadata

Tags: api, metadata, documentation, plantuml, docfx

Is there a sample code for using PlantUml in metadata(Api documentation) Docfx?
it is like this image
[image]

For example, the following picture is another place that's means article menu no on metadat
[image]

Comment: Did you try to "view source" (on the right side) to see the code? Have you tried the plug-in at https://github.com/KevReed/DocFx.Plugins.PlantUml#usage

Comment: yes i saw it and i could it used it but i need to use PlantUml on metadata (api documentation) not other place , it is same this picture

Comment: Look at the source of the code in the project of your image -- you should see how the PlantUML is inserted in the metadata (I assume it's in the comments of the .cs file).

Comment: I saw it, but source code is codes of PlantUml Plugin not sample that contains Docfx sample code, and only explained about use normal it in readme not in metadata or .cs file

Comment: Do you think what tag (PlantUML) is specified in the comments of the .cs file? @Fuhrmanator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It resolved with wrap markdown in a XML CDATA block in the .CS file

[CDATA](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_cdata_sections.htm)

````
///<summary>
///<![CDATA[
///```plantuml
///interface IAnimal {
///Name : string
///}
///```
///]]>
///</summary>
````

[image]

Comment: The CDATA link gives a 404 error